# Has China been funding ethnic militias in Myanmar?

Tags: military, china, myanmar, funding

According to an [article](https://www.mercatornet.com/china_is_losing_control_of_rebel_armies_in_myanmar)
in *Mercator* by [Antonio Graceffo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Graceffo):

> In Burma’s 70-plus years of civil war, China has been funding multiple ethnic resistance armies, as well as serving as the primary benefactor of the junta, playing both sides against the middle, to create the best outcome for Beijing’s foreign policy and economic gain.
>
> [...] Beijing pays ethnic armies to protect Chinese construction projects, even though these same armies are fighting against the junta which Beijing pays to maintain peace in the country.
>
> David Eubank, a former US Special Forces officer and founder of the [Free Burma Rangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Burma_Rangers) aid group [...] described an experience which clearly illustrates the relationship between ethnic armies, the junta, and Beijing: “Once, in Kachin State, I saw the pipelines and bridges linking Burma with China and asked if the Kachin resistance armies had considered blowing them up. The soldiers said, ‘No, because China pays us not to and threatened to slaughter everyone if we did.’”

That China still officially recognizes/supports the official military government of Myanmar can be easily verified even from China-related sources like [SCMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ji6jsBppCw). But these don't seem to mention that China has been funding any insurgents in Myanmar. So did they do that? Is there other evidence besides that anecdote in from that piece?

Comment: I might be missing some nuance here. I thought it's different to *fund* someone, and to *pay* them for a... service, so to speak. For example: if my relative is kidnapped, and I pay a ransom to return them - am I considered to be funding the kidnapper?

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov: yeah, some Chinese (companies?) who aren't exactly known to eschew corruption/bribes abroad (see e.g. D.R. Congo) might be doing that in Myanmar too, more or less willingly, i.e. paying "protection taxes" to some militias.